# Need to identify this plant please?

Tags: identification

This plant comes up every year growing through gravel in a part sunny, part shady position in garden. It comes up in August and flowers late August to late September ( its still in flower now). It dies down to nothing. It does not have woody stems. It's about 2 ft high and 3 foot wide. The leaves are soft and formed in pairs opposite on the stem. The leaves measure at bottom of plant about 12cm long and are smaller at top where the flowers are. They are sort of heart shaped. The flowers have no scent and are trumpet shaped and flower at the top of the leaves in bunches of several at a time- see photo beneath. They have no scent.

Comment: Welcome to the site @judy; you need 10 rep to add photos directly to your question, but if you upload it (StackExchange uses http://imgur.com, but any photo sharing site will do) and add a link, someone can add it for you.  Telling us what climate you have or where you live can help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: If you can't post a photo, what colour are the flowers?

Comment: It appears that the OP posted this question and abandoned it. Without a photo or a better description of the plant, it's anybody's guess what it might be.

Comment: http://www.northcreeknurseries.com/_ccLib/image/plants/DETA-216.jpg Penstemon, Maybe?